# Stop thread in UITableViewCell before it is released

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have this kind of problem where I want to download some images that will be used as thumbnails for each cell.

In order to achieve this behavior, there is a thread working in each `UITableViewCell` that have the role of downloading and saving the image.

But I want to stop the thread from working if the cell is not visible anymore.
Is there some delegate methods for `UITableViewCell` like `viewWillDisappear` that will help me solve this issue?

If I am thinking wrong, Is there any other way that will help me achieve this same behavior?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCell is **only** for rendering something to the screen. The controller that is controlling your tableview should be the one downloading the thumbnails and reload its data once it has the thumbnails.

A tableview only has 1 cell, it copies it in order to display the multiple rows.

Use the delegate method "willDisplayCell" to set the data of your custom tableview cell.

Comment: A table view has about as many cells as shown on screen, and those are not copied.

Comment: if you have multiple columns maybe, but if you have multiple rows you still only have 1 cell instance which is copied over.

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt thank you for your reply! I knew that, but I thought that it would be easier for me to implement what I wanted if there was such functions! In anycase everything is working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

Due the reusable cell mechanism a single instante of `UITableViewCell` can be reused for display different data so `UITableViewCell` is not meant to be used for this logic but only for presentation purpose.
I suggest you to rethink your app logic